# How does TransactionScope work with multiple queries?

Tags: .net, transactionscope

I am using `TransactionScope` and then saving the data in database.

Within the same transaction after data save, I am changing the value of object sent to save.

Now my question is: will it save changed data or not? And how the transction works(save data in data base with each call or it saves data after `transactionObject.Commit()` call)?

Answer (score 0):

The data is saved permnently only if you call `transactionObject.Commit()`. Even if you change the saved object, it will not reflect the changes, unless you save the object again.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that TransactionScope should commit data with `Complete` method (see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)).
Please read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx).

It states that:

> It is merely a way of informing the transaction manager of your status. After calling this method, you can no longer access the ambient transaction via the Current property, and trying to do so results in an exception being thrown.

and:

> The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the End Using statement if the TransactionScope object created the transaction. If it did not create the transaction, the commit occurs whenever Commit is called by the owner of the CommittableTransaction object.

However, the easiest way would be to check it with a sample code in a specific case ;).